# User points from different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have found a problem I can't solve by myself.

I have users in table AE_Users where I store their special Points
Additionaly I have AE_Event table where I store events the users can join to, and for these events I am storing play time in seconds (timestamp) which is taken care of by CRON script checking players on server. 
There is another table named AE_EventJoin where user is stored when he joins one of the events (so there can be multiple records of one user joining multiple event IDs)

I am able to calculate one user's point count by using 3 SQLs in PHP script:

```
SELECT `SteamID` FROM AE_Users WHERE `SteamID` = $SteamID
SELECT SUM(`EventInfo`) FROM AE_Events WHERE ID IN (SELECT `EventID` FROM AE_EventJoin WHERE `JoinType` = 1 AND `SteamID` = '$SteamID')
SELECT `Points` FROM AE_Users WHERE `SteamID` = $SteamID
```

but now I need to get top 5 users with most points and I really couldn't solve how to query the DB to give them to me.

I don't want to query DB for all users and then sort them in PHP, that would be too ugly.

I believe there is a way on how to calculate the user points from single SQL query. I tried to build it myself, but it is not working as expected. I was able to come up with this:

```
SELECT T1.`SteamID`, T1.`Points` AS PointCount, SUM(T2.`EventInfo`) AS PointCount FROM AE_Users T1, AE_Events T2 WHERE T2.ID IN (SELECT `EventID` FROM AE_EventJoin WHERE `JoinType` = 1 AND `SteamID` = T1.`SteamID`) ORDER BY PointCount LIMIT 5
```

which returns this: [phpMyAdmin result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6LwJ.png)

and that is wrong. It return only one user and the first PointCount is user's special point count which is correct, but the second PointCount is totally wrong viz. picture
[phpMyAdmin Event points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SseO.png)

And I would like to merge those two variables into one PointCount but GROUP BY command didn't allow me to do it because of some error. It is not a big issue though, I can merge them in PHP easily.

So is there any way on how to get the information I need from tables with structure like I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a group by clause , so try this:

```
SELECT T1.`SteamID`, max(T1.`Points`) AS PointCount, SUM(T2.`EventInfo`) AS PointCount
FROM AE_Users T1
INNER JOIN AE_Events T2
 ON T2.ID IN (SELECT `EventID` FROM AE_EventJoin
              WHERE `JoinType` = 1
                AND `SteamID` = T1.`SteamID`)
GROUP BY T1.`SteamID`
ORDER BY PointCount 
LIMIT 5
```

Also, you used implicit(comma separated) join syntax, please try to avoid this and use the correct syntax of explicit joins like in my solution.

You didn't post your table structures so it was hard to guess what exactly do you need, but it is something similar to this.

This query can also be written with a join instead of IN()

```
SELECT T1.`SteamID`, max(T1.`Points`) AS PointCount, SUM(T2.`EventInfo`) AS PointCount
FROM AE_Users T1
INNER JOIN `EventID` T3
 ON(t1.`steamID` = t3.`steamID` and  `JoinType` = 1 AND `SteamID` = T1.`SteamID`)
INNER JOIN AE_Events T2
 ON (T2.ID = T3.ID) 
GROUP BY T1.`SteamID`
ORDER BY PointCount 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Thanks, your (first code) solution was extremely helpful. I changed it a little bit to compute second PointCount as SUM(T2.`EventInfo`)+T1.`Points` and changed order to DESC, and it is working as expected. Thank you very much :)